# How repeating field values ​​in "EntityReference select list widget" as I would with "autocomplete widget"

Tags: entities

my question is how to display "select list widget" like "autocomplete widget" when
I create or edit an entity, I mean with "add another field". I need this
because I need repeating field values ​​in "EntityReference select list
widget" as I would with "autocomplete widget" or as shown in the module "Double Field".
thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found everything I was looking for in the [Multiple Selects](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_selects) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides a widget called Multiple Selects list for the the following fields types:
>
> - entity_reference
> - node_reference
> - user_reference
> - taxonomy_term_reference
> - list_integer
> - list_float
> - list_text
> - list_boolean
> - commerce_product_reference
>
> Rather than having a multi-select field, this modules allows you to have multiple select fields with the traditional FieldAPI 'Add another item' button.